# Rails Active Storage remove attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a small rails project. I have a user model created using `devise` gem. The user is allowed to add multiple photos on `devise/registrations/edit` and for this purpose I have used `active_storage` to store the images.
Also, these images must be able to be deleted. How I can add a delete button to delete these images one by one?

**devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-6">
  <%= f.label :photos_of_you %> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-6">
  <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <% if resource.images.attached? %>
  <div class="d-inline-block image-gallery">
   <% (0...resource.images.count).each do |i| %>
    <%= image_tag (resource.images[i]) %>
   <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

on **application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:full_name, :gender])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:full_name, :gender, :avatar, images: [] ])
  end
end
```

on model **user.rb**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one_attached :avatar, dependent: :destroy
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Please include examples of code. What do you have in your model, controller and view at the moment

Comment: Hi I just added examples of code.

Comment: can you add some of the contents of the "registrations_controller"? and if possible, extracts of the routes `rake routes`, with any references to "user" or "registration"?